Cause of stale DNS records
There is a domain name (for example, example.com) that uses Register.com as its domain registrar and uses Register.com's name servers (let's say dns1xx.register.com and dns1xy.register.com). The domain had the following DNS records defined:
A  *    50.xxx.xxx.xxx
A  sub  50.xxx.xxx.xxx
A  @    50.xxx.xxx.xxx
A  www  50.xxx.xxx.xxx

The domain also has SPF records, DMARC records, and MX records pointing to Outlook. The TTL for all records is 2 hours.
The web host, who controls 50.xxx.xxx.xxx, is moving to another data center and asked the domain owner to update the DNS records to point to 67.xxx.xxx.xxx. The domain owner updates the DNS records to look like this:
A  *    67.xxx.xxx.xxx
A  sub  67.xxx.xxx.xxx
A  @    67.xxx.xxx.xxx
A  www  50.xxx.xxx.xxx

The mistake is pointed out, and the domain owner updates the www record to point to the new IP two days later. However, for the next week, the resolution for www.example.com randomly switches between 50.xxx.xxx.xxx and 67.xxx.xxx.xxx:
dig www.example.com a @dns1xx.register.com
www.example.com.    7200    IN      A       67.xxx.xxx.xxx

dig www.example.com a @dns1xx.register.com
www.example.com.    7200    IN      A       50.xxx.xxx.xxx

What could possibly be causing these old records to randomly appear? Is there anything that the web host could be doing that would cause the old records to be sticking? Is this in any way related to the PTR records for 50.xxx.xxx.xxx?

Welcome to Server Fault! In many cases mentioning the actual domain name is essential for the community to be able to help diagnose DNS issues. This may be one too. Please refer to this Q&A for our recommendations with regards to how and what (not) to obfuscate in your questions.

@HBruijn Thank you for your help. The issue had resolved itself a few days before I posted the question, so the actual domain name wouldn't help in this case. I'm just asking what the most likely cause of this might be so that we can learn from it and prevent it from happening again.

A primary nameserver typically syncs the zonefile to one or more secondary nameservers. When this sync fails, most often the SOA serial number in the zonefile on the primary nameserver has not been updated. So when editing the zonefile to change things, it is important to also update the SOA serial number.
You can check things like this by using a tool such as Zonemaster: https://zonemaster.se/en/run-test
Or, do "dig soa example.com @nameserver1" and "dig soa example.com @nameserver2". This will show you that the two nameservers have the same SOA serial.

Note that many DNS providers use others mechanisms than zone files and zone transfers for storing/replicating/synchronizing zone data between name servers reducing the significance of the SOA serial number.

A common mistake could be that rather than updating the A record for www   with the new IP-address a second A record was added for the new IP-address , resulting in a Round-Robin record with both the old and the new IP-addresses https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS
